# Is this a compact subset of an open set?

Tags: general-topology

Let's suppose I have the open set $$(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$$
Is $[-0.1,0.1] \times (-1,1)$ a compact subset of this open set? What troubles me is that isn't a compact set supposed to be closed?

Comment: It is not even a subset of it: $\langle-1,0\rangle\notin(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean something like $\{ 0 \} \times (-1,1)$ instead?

Comment: It important to note that *open* and *closed* are notions that depend on the ambient topology. (For example any set is open and closed in itself.) In contrast, compactness is an intrinsic property of a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It important to note that *open* and *closed* are notions that depend on the ambient topology. (For example any set is open and closed in itself.) In contrast, compactness is an intrinsic property of a space.

In this setting, consider $\{0 \} \times (-1,1)$. It is closed *as a subspace of $[-1,1] \times (-1,1)$*, but not as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore it cannot be compact, as this would violate the Heine-Borel theorem. (Or using less machinery: compact sets are closed in a Hausdorff space.)

Comment: @Controller I figured. It doesn't change anything substantial to my answer (replace $\{0\}$ by $[-0.1,0.1]$)

Answer (score 0):

You can see this explicitly, as well. Consider $\mathcal{O} = \{ (-0.2, 0.2) \times (-1, 1-\tfrac{1}{n})\; | \; n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\} \}$. Then $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of $[-0.1, 0.1] \times (-1, 1)$ with no finite subcover.